# How to change an input value after clicking on a link_to?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, input, link-to

```
<input class="code_rabais" id="coupon_code" name="rabais" type="text">
<div class="ajout_rabais"><%= link_to "add", '#', :id => 'add_coupon' %></div>
```

I want to reset the input value of code_rabais to "" after the user clicked on "add". What is the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as following:

```
link_to "add", '#', id: 'add_coupon', onclick: "$('#coupon_code').val('');return false;"
```

The other way is to add an event listener on the click event of the link_to:

```
link_to "add", '#', :id => 'add_coupon'

# javascript in the same view 
$('#add_coupon').on('click', function(event) {
  $('#coupon_code').val('');
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: I think, second way is a little bit cleaner. You probably should add `event.preventDefault()` to second solution, which will prevent `#` to show in address path.